# How to extract timestamp from filename list in python and convert to Timestamp format?

Tags: python, regex, timestamp

Here is the list of filenames with timestamp in it. I need loop through the list and extract only the timestamp value in the list and strip the values and convert to timestamp.

```
s = ['Asbdnfe_20200404_000101.csv',
     'sdndvd_20200404_010202.csv',
     'vdfvdfvdfvd_20190303_030303.csv']

length = len(s)
for i in range(length):
    match = re.search(r"_((\d+)_(\d+))", s[i])
    print(match.group(1))
```

Result:
20200404_000001,
20200404_010202,
20190303_030303

But what I want is:

```
[2020-04-04 00:01:01.000,
2020-04-04 01:02:02.000,
2019-03-03 03:03:03.000]
```

Comment: We can format the string to a datetime object by using the specific formatters easily by using datetime.strptime

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime%20strptime#datetime.datetime.strptime) to convert the extracted strings into `datetime` objects:

```
from datetime import datetime
import re

s = ['Asbdnfe_20200404_000101.csv','sdndvd_20200404_010202.csv','vdfvdfvdfvd_20190303_030303.csv']

for f in s:
    match = re.search(r"_((\d+)_(\d+))", f)
    d = datetime.strptime(match.group(1), '%Y%m%d_%H%M%S')
    print(d)
```

Output:

```
2020-04-04 00:01:01
2020-04-04 01:02:02
2019-03-03 03:03:03
```

If you want to print the dates with milliseconds, use [`datetime.strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime%20strptime#datetime.datetime.strftime):

```
print(d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3])
```

The `%f` specifier prints microseconds, so we use `[:-3]` to strip it back to a millisecond value.

To produce a list of results, just append them to a list rather than printing them:

```
d = []
for f in s:
    match = re.search(r"_((\d+)_(\d+))", f)
    dt = datetime.strptime(match.group(1), '%Y%m%d_%H%M%S')
    d.append(dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3])
    
print(d)
```

Or you can use a list comprehension:

```
d = [datetime.strptime(re.search(r"_((\d+)_(\d+))", f).group(1), '%Y%m%d_%H%M%S').strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3] for f in s]
```

The output is the same:

```
['2020-04-04 00:01:01.000', '2020-04-04 01:02:02.000', '2019-03-03 03:03:03.000']
```

Comment: @Manak no worries - I hope it was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use DateTime parsing and formating as follows

```
from datetime import datetime 
import re

s = ['Asbdnfe_20200404_000101.csv',
     'sdndvd_20200404_010202.csv',
     'vdfvdfvdfvd_20190303_030303.csv']

length = len(s)
for i in range(length):
    match = re.search(r"_((\d+)_(\d+))", s[i])
    #print(match.group(1))
    print(datetime.strptime(match.group(1), '%Y%m%d_%H%M%S').strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3])
```

You will get the output as

```
2020-04-04 00:01:01.000
2020-04-04 01:02:02.000
2019-03-03 03:03:03.000
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you need to do the same thing to a bunch of similar inputs, look for a common *pattern* and start there.  In this case, the pattern is pretty simple, so the regex is actually overkill.

```
import datetime as dt
from pathlib import Path

s = ['Asbdnfe_20200404_000101.csv',
     'sdndvd_20200404_010202.csv',
     'vdfvdfvdfvd_20190303_030303.csv']

datetimes = []
for filename in s:
    name = Path(filename).stem    # or os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
    timestamp_str = name[-15:]
    file_dt = dt.strptime(timestamp_str, '%Ym%d_%H%M%S')
    datetimes.append(file_dt)
```

All your file names are in the form of `<some_prefix>_<YYYYMMDD>_<HHMMSS>.csv`. So no matter what `<some_prefix>` is, you can index the string from the right, and pull out the date and time information in the same way every time.
And as others have noted, once you do, the `datetime` module's `strptime` function exists exactly for this use.

Even if you have a case where the inputs aren't as clean and regular as the few file names you posted, just look for a slightly more abstract pattern and write code around that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `datetime`

```
import datetime import datetime

s = ['Asbdnfe_20200404_000101.csv',
     'sdndvd_20200404_010202.csv',
     'vdfvdfvdfvd_20190303_030303.csv']

length = len(s)
for i in range(length):
    match = re.search(r"_((\d+)_(\d+))", s[i])
    time_str = match.group(1)
    print(datetime.strptime(time_str, "%Y%m%d_%H%M%S").strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```