# Extract timestamp in file name

Tags: r, regex, timestamp

I have a vector containing file names:

```r
Filenames = c("blabla_bli_20140524_002532_000.wav", 
    "20201025_231205.wav", 
    "ble_20190612_220013_012.wav", 
    "X-20150312_190225_Blablu.wav", 
    "0000125.wav")
```

Of course the real vector is longer. I need to extract the timestamp from the name so to obtain the following result in date format:

```r
Result = c("2014-05-24 00:25:32.000", 
    "2020-10-25 23:12:05.000", 
    "2019-06-12 22:00:13.012", 
    "2015-03-12 19:02:25.000", 
    NA)
```

Note that sometimes characters are present before or after the timestamp, and that some file names display the milliseconds while some do not (in this case they are assumed to be 000 milliseconds). I also need to obtain something like "NA" if the file name does not have the timestamp in it.

I found what looks like [a good solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62589477/how-to-extract-timestamp-from-filename-list-in-python-and-convert-to-timestamp-f) but it is in python and I don't know how to translate it in R. I tried this, which is not working:

```r
str_extract(Filenames, regex("_((\d+)_(\d+))"))
Error: '\d' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""_((\d"
```

Comment: It seems to me that you need to escape the backslash with a backslash, otherwise r will think you are using a \d escape character, which is not recognized. Use \\d+ instead of \d+.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `gsub` to extract your datetime part by pattern, then rely (mostly) on the parsing of datetimes by POSIX standards. The only catch is that in POSIX, milliseconds must be expressed as *ss.mmm* (fractional seconds), so you need to replace the _ with a .

```
timestamps <- gsub(".*?(([0-9]{8}_[0-9]{6})(_([0-9]{3}))?).*?$", "\\2.\\4", Filenames)
timestamps
[1] "20140524_002532.000" "20201025_231205."    "20190612_220013.012"
[4] "20150312_190225."    "0000125.wav"
```

We have captured the datetime section (`\\2`), added a dot, then the (optional) millisecond section (`\\4`), without the underscore. Note that the mismatched filename remains unchanged - that's ok.

Now we specify the datetime format using the [POSIX specification](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strptime.html) to first parse the strings, then print them in a different format:

```
times <- as.POSIXct(timestamps, format="%Y%m%d_%H%M%OS")
format(times, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS3")
[1] "2014-05-24 00:25:32.000" "2020-10-25 23:12:05.000" "2019-06-12 22:00:13.012"
[4] "2015-03-12 19:02:25.000" NA
```

Note that the string that was not a timestamp just got turned into NA, so you can easily get rid of it here. Also, if you want to see the milliseconds printed out, you seed to use the `%OS` (fractional seconds) format, *plus* the number of digits (0-6) you want printed - in this case, `%OS3`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```r
library(stringr)
rx <- "(\\d{4})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})_(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(?:_(\\d+))?"
Filenames = c("blabla_bli_20140524_002532_000.wav", "20201025_231205.wav", "ble_20190612_220013_012.wav", "X-20150312_190225_Blablu.wav", "0000125.wav")
m <- str_match(Filenames, rx)
result <- ifelse(is.na(m[,8]), 
    str_c(m[,2], "-", m[,3], "-", m[,4], " ", m[,5], ":", m[,6], ":", m[,7], ".000"),
    str_c(m[,2], "-", m[,3], "-", m[,4], " ", m[,5], ":", m[,6], ":", m[,7], ".", m[,8]))
result
```

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/rHZKLK). Output:

```
> result
[1] "2014-05-24 00:25:32.000"
[2] "2020-10-25 23:12:05.000"
[3] "2019-06-12 22:00:13.012"
[4] "2015-03-12 19:02:25.000"
[5] NA
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SNQrWL/1). It captures parts of the datetime string into separate groups. If the last group (`(\d+)` in the `(?:_(\d+))?` optional non-capturing group matching milliseconds) is matched, we add it preceded with a dot, else, we add `.000`.

Comment: Thank you so much, this works! Thank you also for the link to the regex demo, it will be incredibly useful for my future needs also.

Comment: would it not be easier to use sprintf for your manual reconstruction of the datetime string? That way, you can ifelse only the m[,8] parameter.