# Parse timestamp from a txt file?

Tags: python, datetime, python-requests, timestamp

I have a large text file on the web that I am using requests to obtain and parse data from. The text file begins each line with a format like [Mon Oct 10 08:58:26 2022]. How can I get the latest 7 days or convert only the datetime to an object or string for storing and parsing later? I simply want to extract the timestamps from the log and print them

Comment: If you are able to control the log output, make a data structure of list, imagine a list of `json`, just iterate it and load the relevant time field from it.

Comment: thanks. i cannot control the output

Comment: In that case, you need to be able to specify the delimiter between strings and introduce some logic to each slice. Can you post here an example of the output? (Not just a slice, but a full response).

Answer (score 0):

You can use TimedRotatingFileHandler for daily or 7-days logs.

[read more about timed rotating file handler here](https://in%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44718204/python-how-to-create-log-file-everyday-using-logging-module)

and

[read more about extracting timestamps from files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62589477/how-to-extract-timestamp-from-filename-list-in-python-and-convert-to-timestamp-f)

Comment: but what is the datetime (%y%t etc) format for matching my syntax?

Comment: you can use this: datetime.strptime('Mon Oct 10 08:58:26 2022', '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y')

Comment: thanks. this helps for the format, but when anything else in the line isnt a date theres an error thrown (the entire object/line has more than dates in it), i get errors for it (unconverted data remains). I simply want to extract the text matching the format

file_dt = dt.datetime.strptime(line, '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y')
        print(file_dt)

Comment: It can be handled using regex very easily. If you print a few lines of your file as an example, I will help you to solve it.

Comment: Thank you, very helpful. I will try to explain what I am trying to do:

I have a log file that logs information like so (among other things), but each new line begins with the timestamp format:


[Sun Oct 09 06:14:26 2022] Wiladoc is browsing your wares.
[Sun Oct 09 06:14:38 2022]  purchased 1 Aged Nightfall for (1000p)

I want to extract the timestamps from this log and store them into an object. Ultimately, I want to automatically return the last 7 days of purchases along with the name of the purchaser (purchasers are always on the line above the purchased item)

Comment: *Should note that eventually these lines are to be separated and parsed into a db...eventually

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell me if this snippet solves your problem?

```python
from datetime import datetime

log_line = "[Sun Oct 09 06:14:26 2022] Wiladoc is browsing your wares."
_datetime = log_line[1:25]
_datetime_strp = datetime.strptime(_datetime, '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y')

print(_datetime)
print(_datetime_strp)
```

Comment: I will check, but Wiladoc is usually a wildcard and not always the same here